# I am using Navigator.push it works in the child page, but when I put it in main its giving an error

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use Navigator.push to navigate to a child component. when I use this in header component under onTap this works as expected but I am trying to bring to main it fails. any help is appreciated

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:questionx/theme/header.dart';
import "package:questionx/second.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Application',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.blue),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: const AppHeader(
        title: "Home Page",
        titleWidget: Icon(Icons.access_time),
        leading: Icon(
          Icons.home,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        showActionIcon: true,
        onMenuActionTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondPage()));
        },
      ),

      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

header.dart

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class AppHeader extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const AppHeader({
    Key? key,
    this.title = '',
    this.leading,
    this.titleWidget,
    this.showActionIcon = false,
    this.onMenuActionTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final Widget? leading;
  final Widget? titleWidget;
  final bool showActionIcon;
  final VoidCallback? onMenuActionTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 25 / 2.5),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
              child: titleWidget == null
                  ? Center(
                      child: Text(title,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 16,
                              color: Colors.white)))
                  : Center(child: titleWidget!)),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              leading ??
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: const Offset(-14, 0),
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.menu,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                  ),
              if (showActionIcon)
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: const Offset(10, 0),
                  child: InkWell(
                      onTap: onMenuActionTap,
                      child: const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Icon(Icons.menu),
                      )),
                )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size(double.maxFinite, 80);
}
```

second.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:questionx/theme/header.dart';

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppHeader(
          leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              icon: const BackButton())),
      body: const Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to make changes to onMenuActionTap in main but any change that make is not yielding in a right code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encapsulate your Scaffold widget with Builder widget and it will work. The reason that it does not work in main is because of widget tree. Because your widget is not the child of parent widget, it throws an error.